# Trying to access state outside of a function in React

Tags: reactjs, this, state

I'm simply trying to access state outside of a function. What would be the best way to go about that? I just want something to render based on if the state is "" or not:

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        locationInput: "",
        data: "",
        };
    }




    validateForm() {
    return this.state.locationInput.length > 0
    }


    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.id]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({data: httpGet(this.state.locationInput)})
        console.log(this.state.data)



    }

    tableRender = null;

    if(this.state.data !== "") //this is where I'm getting the 'unexpected keyword error'
    {
        tableRender = <Table data={this.state.data} />
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not set tableRender in the constructor?

Comment: You're in a class, not a function. Either do that part in the `render` method, or create a new method to wrap that logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In React's stateful Component, we must have render function to carry all the html elements. In your case, you can do make a condition on a state like below to render by state's value,

```js
export default class Home extends Component {
  ...
  ...
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.data !== "" && (<Table data={this.state.data} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add this to the render method?

```
render(){
   if(this.state.data !== ""){
      tableRender = <Table data={this.state.data} />
   }

   return(
      <div>{tableRender}</div>
   )

}
```